# Парсинг изменяемых данных из приложения Android

Tags: java, android, парсер

Есть сайт, на котором данные одного поля обновляются после нажатия кнопки. При этом сам сайт не меняется, только одно поле на нем. Если я захочу это спарсить с компьютера я легко сделаю это используя silenium. Но как парсить описанный выше случай(или например результаты после скрола) в приложении для android?

Comment: А http://selendroid.io/ не то (просто сам не в курсе)? Другой вариант `WebView` + `JS` - вроде можно использовать в скрытом режиме. Третий - открыть код страницы, найти как реализован нужный функционал и повторить.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю про  selendroid. Нашел у кнопки метода вида onclick() = "pages('pre',4)", его можно вызвать программно, без браузера на экране и нажатия?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужен jsoup.

Comment: @Valeriy, `jsoup` чисто парсер - он не умеет нажимать на кнопки и выполнять скрипты

Comment: @Keker, `pages('pre',4)` - это скорее всего `JS`- функция, нужно найти её код и посмотреть что она делает. Вызвать её без браузера вообще - нельзя, но повторить то, что она делает можно.